# getListAdapter inside SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to save the SMS received in SmsReceiver class extends using BroadcastReceiver.

This is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Message>) getListAdapter();
Message message = null;
```

But it seems `getListAdapter()` is not part of BroadcastReceiver, so it throws an error "The method getListAdapter() is undefined for the type SmsReceiver".

Anyone know how to declare the code above inside BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Why do you need an `Adapter` for saving messages?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't need that.